# Какой язык выбрать для создания бота для работы с сайтом?

Tags: парсер, бот

Мне нужен бот, который будет брать данные из таблицы на сайте (данные расположены между тегами и их нужно будет как-то изъять), анализировать эти данные и на основании определённых критериев, установленных мной, бот должен нажимать на определённые кнопки на сайте, а кнопок этих может быть несколько сотен, как и объектов из таблицы.

На каком языке мне лучше всего начать это делать и какие гайды для этого использовать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Бот не нажимает на кнопки! Он способен отправлять запросы, принимать ответы, взаимодействовать со скриптами. Хотя... Слышал про Arduino? =D

Comment: Python ? Уроки по парсингу с использованием bs4 (BeautifulSoup) , а вот если нужно нажимать кнопки на сайте то Selenium.